# What image processing techniques would help to seprate numeric text from these images?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, captcha

I have been testing my image processing skills on black and white captchas and I would like to try the image processing against more complex captchas like the following:

[type one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aphQ0.gif)

[type 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcGFI.gif)

Can anyone help me with any information or resources as to where to go from here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pytesser or Tesseract as your OCR. Try to Google "OCR - Python" and you will find many Python - OCR libraries or programs that can achieve what you want.

Here's an example using pytesser:

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesser import *
temp_img = Image.open('your_image.jpg')
your_digit = image_to_string(temp_img)
print your_digit
```